# Conditional to determine if search.php page is the current template

Tags: templates, search, conditional-tags

I have a specific CSS-file for my search results, so the search.php template. I want a PHP if-condition to determine if the current template is the search.php template, so that I can load that CSS-file with `wp_enqueue`. The condition should work in the functions.php file.

I'm not entirely sure if I can use `is_search()` for this. Can anyone confirm I can use `is_search()` and, if that's not the case, provide an alternative?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress conditional functions will not tell you which template *file* is used. They tell you what the current request is for. Which file is loaded for that type of request is determined by the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

So, `is_search()` will tell you if search.php is being used if the current request is a search, and the current theme includes a search.php. If the theme does not include search.php, `is_search()` will still return `true` if index.php is used, as per the template hierarchy.

That's the long way of saying that if your theme has search.php, then yes, use `is_search()`.

Comment: Thanks Jacob! Also for the explanation about the type of request and the template hierarchy. (PS: I can accept it in 6 minutes.)